# Displaying variable on a label Tkinter python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I read some similiar questions here but couldn't fix my code, so i ask.

I'm working on a little program with a gui, press a button, it adds 1 to a variable, press the second button, it subtract, press the third button, it prints the current value of the variable. Now i want it to print the variable always on the gui, on a label, i've read how to do it and i thought i got it, but when i went to run the code the label was not working. It runs though, so no error message.

```
from Tkinter import *

class experiment:


    def __init__(self, master):
        global students
        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack()

        self.addbutton = Button(frame, text="Add Student", command=self.addstudent, bg="black", fg="white")
        self.addbutton.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky = E)

        self.subbutton = Button(frame,text="Subtract Student", command=self.subtractstudent, bg="black", fg="white")
        self.subbutton.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky = E)

        self.checkbutton = Button(frame,text="Check Record", command=self.checkstudentrec, bg="black", fg="white")
        self.checkbutton.grid(row=0, column=3, sticky= E )

        self.quitButton = Button(frame,text="Quit", command=frame.quit)
        self.quitButton.grid(row=2, column=3, sticky=W)

        self.label1 = Label(frame, textvariable = students)
        self.label1.grid(row=2, column=1)

    def addstudent(self):
        global students
        students = students + 1
        print "\n Student Added"
    def subtractstudent(self):
        global students
        students = students - 1
        print "\n Student Deleted"
    def checkstudentrec(self):
        print students
        print "\n Student Record Found"

root = Tk()
students = 0
b = experiment(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Label `textvariable` parameter expect [special kind of tkinter/tcl variables](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm). These ones can be traced, in the meaning that any piece of the program can subscribe to their value and be notified when it changes.

Thus, initializing students with an `IntVar` and adapting you increment code should do the job.

```
def addstudent(self):
    global students
    students.set(students.get() + 1)

#(...)
students = IntVar()
```